# With Spring transaction manager configured, when will the db connection established?

Tags: database, spring, transactions, connection

Supposed there is a method `getAssignedTasks` in a class named `TaskService` and this method actually retrieves information from two datasources, `dao1.getInfo()` and `dao2.getMoreInfo()`. The question is when the database connection is actually established?

I supposed the connection to datasource1 is established when calling `dao1.getInfo()` and at this point of time (`dao2.getMoreInfo()` not yet invoked) the connection to datasource2 is not established. Am I right? Will the connections both be established when calling the `getAssignedTasks` method right away?

the spring configuration is something like below

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is specification defined behavior (if not - this may be different across different JTA implementations), but with Artomikos jdbc JTA implementation it seems that connection is taken only when it is needed and at the beginning of transaction.

This seems to be logical since in some methods connection form the second (or third, or) DataSource may be not used and taking it from the pool will be just useless overhead.

I have written a small test to investigate this that can be found on [github](https://github.com/isopov/multiple-ds-tx-test/commit/730bdc2d820c95813062eb250e7c00fe224d444b). You may debug through it for your own investigation.